# Identiyserver4 how to handle 2 users in the same browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

Scenario:
Identityserver4 + aspnet core identity and one aspnet core mvc client
Questions:
How to manage 2 users logging into the same browser at the same time? Do I have to make sure that only one user is logged in at a time or can I use several users at the same time?

Comment: How would that be possible, two users in the same browser? Are those real users? Or do you want a user to use two different identities?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i use 2 tabs in my browser and log in to each tab with a different account

Comment: as this is all based on cookies, those tabs share the cookies. Open a different browser; use one in private mode or use the feature of Chrome to create user profiles and then switch your chrome session to the user of choice, those don't share cookies.

Comment: Can I say badly to a user using 2 different browsers. Next problem I've discovered:
Login page->Account A->MVC-Client->Login page->Account B->MVC-Client I get the data from account A

Comment: If you have one user then why use two accounts? Identityserver4 is about identifying the user: who is the user. Seems you are mixing this with authorization: what is the user allowed to do? Why does the user have to login twice? The user is already identitfied (SSO).

Comment: One user /one account, the user is allowed to enter the mvc client after login... but what if I have 2 accounts so 2 users and then log in both as described above?

Comment: If there are two users then they can use their own browser ;) But seriously, the SSO cookie prevents to have two users logged in at the same time in the same browser. You should make sure that the first user is logged out (SSO) when the second user logs in.

Comment: Now we're getting closer, how should a complete logout work when logging in?

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html

Comment: ok thanks but that means no matter if front or backchannel logout, i always have to render an iframe that logs out all clients?

Comment: It means that you should consider another strategy. Like I said, IdentityServer4 is about identifying the user. It shouldn't be necessary for the user to use another account. Build in some sort of impersonation. Try to make it in a way that one user can use the app from different perspectives without having the user to use two accounts. On the client keep track of the current role or user. And redesign authorization.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Facebook login scenario.
you can save usernames into a cookie and show them a list of logged in users. after clicking on it a password will appear.

Comment: What do you mean by a Facebook login scenario? You should add some details. Though I can't imagine any scenario where a password will 'magically' appear.

Comment: you can add multiple users in your app and when you want to switch between users a password is required.so you just need to save usernames in a session or cookie.